# Restoring redis running on docker from dump.rdb

Tags: redis, docker-compose

What I want to do is to use a dump.rdb that I've taken from a production server, and use it in my development environment, that is defined by a very simple compose file.

For simplicity, assume that my app is the same as this [compose example from the docker docs](https://docker.github.io/compose/gettingstarted/) for redis and flask, so the docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '2'
 services:
   web:
     build: .
     ports:
      - "5000:5000"
     volumes:
      - .:/code
     depends_on:
      - redis
   redis:
     image: redis
```

This persists redis data between restarts, but you just cannot access the redis files as there is no volume mounted for redis in the docker-compose.yml. 
So I change my compose file to mount a volume for redis, and I also want to force redis to persist data and the [official redis image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) say that happens if I use 'appendonly'.

```
redis:
  image: redis
  command: redis-server --appendonly yes
  volumes:
    - ./redis:/data
```

If I do this, my data are persisted, as they were in the original example, and I can now see a dump.rdb and and appendonly.aof in the /redis path. The problem is, if I want to restore from a dump.rdb I need to turn off appendonly (for example, see digital ocean's how-to-back-up-and-restore-your-redis-data-on-ubuntu-14-04), and without append-only I cannot see how to get the compose file to write to the volume.

How can I produce a docker compose that will persist redis in a volume where I can switch the dump.rdb files, and therefore insert the production snapshot into my development environment?

**Update**
The following compose works, but be patient when testing, as the creation of the dump.rdb is not instant (hence it seeming like it failed). Also the redis official image doc, implies you have to use appendonly when you don't:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  volumes:
    - ./redis:/data
```

Answer (score 1):

The appendonly part is just to make sure that you don't lose data, but since you already have the dump.rdb from your server you don't need to worry about that: you can either remove the append only flag or remove 'command' entirely since it will then fall back to the image default which is just 'redis-server'.

<s>I have a similar setup [here](https://github.com/kraftman/filtta/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) and it writes/loads the dump.rdb files fine.</s> (404)

Comment: Thanks @Chris - comparing the compose files, one difference is you are building your own redis image `build redis` (c.f. `image redis`), so I thought it might be that. I tried using your redis Dockerfile to see if it was and I still wasn't getting the expected result. I therefore reverted to the standard image, removing 'command', and having a volume there. That seems to fix it some of the time - sometimes I have to restart the container. I _think_ the problem is that the `dump.rdb` file creation wasn't being triggered, but shutting down the container triggers it.

Comment: @chris by removing append only don't you think the redis container will not backup the data when new data is added? That is suppose new data gets added and somehow my container stops, so if i restart the container will the newly added data still be there?